# Dropdown menu show on hover doesn't work after jquery sets css to display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu that has `display: none` and when hovering on parent it has  `display: block` via CSS. The dropdown menu links to anchors on the same page, so when I click I want the dropdown to disappear so I have on click

`$('.dropdown-menu').css("display", "none")`

However, the jquery has now overridden the `display: block` that happens on hover. How can I keep the previous functionality while hiding the menu when clicking?

[JSFiddle of my code](https://jsfiddle.net/dc38u09p/)

Comment: Can you please show the code whatever you have done ?

Comment: Put out html+js+css for getting answers

Comment: Your JS is overriding your CSS because it puts the CSS property inline. You can solve this by adding `!important` to the hover state in the CSS file or by doing the hover effect in JS as well.

Comment: Correction: `!important` will not work, because then you can't hide the menu on click, so your only option is making the hover in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added another function to show the content again and edited your original a bit.

https://jsfiddle.net/dc38u09p/6/

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.hide-on-click', function(event) {
    $('.dropdown-content').hide();
});

$('.dropdown').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('.dropdown-content').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `.hover()` from jquery ?

Comment: You should be adding that as a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add this into your javascript

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.dropdown', function(event) {
    $('.dropdown-content').css("display","block");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Best then to use jQuery for hover and click actions.

Here it is quick solution:

```js
// menu hover
$(".dropdown").mouseover(function() {
    $('.dropdown-content').css("display", "block");
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $('.dropdown-content').css("display", "none");
  });
//menu click
$(".dropdown").click(function() {
  $('.dropdown-content').css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```